# Guid gets overwritten on form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, savechanges

When I load this form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Category Description</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CategoryID)   
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Language)<br />
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new {} )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>


</fieldset>
```

The fields have the following values:

[image]

But after submitting the form, in the POST Method, the ID gets overwritten by the other Guid and the Language Field is null.

[image]

The Data Model looks like this:

```
public partial class Category_Description
 {
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

EDIT:
On Request the Post-Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CategoryDescription_Edit(Category_Description model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = dataService.SaveChanges(model);
            if (result)
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

And just in case the dataService.SaveChanges as well:

```
public bool SaveChanges(object model)
    {
        Portal_Context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return Portal_Context.SaveChanges() > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show  us the post method of your controller?

Comment: @Yogi Sure, here you go.

Comment: Not much clue :(. but one observation is that the ID is replaced by CategoryId actually. There must be some trivial tricky miss

Comment: @Yogi Yes :D I figured out that much. I hope so, It works just fine for other forms.

Comment: `DisplayFor` does not generate an input element so its normal than language comes back as null. As for the Id, is it possible that in your url the Id is the categoryId? Because I think that route parameters would take preference over form data during the binding

Comment: @DanielJ.G. The url has indeed the Guid of the category... CategoryDescription_Edit/f326ab3c-b755-4bde-91b5-ded2a55428df. Is there a way to solve this other that changing the id in the url?

Comment: One option would be using a view model different from the entity model that only has the categoryId. You would then map from the view model to the entity before saving to the db. Another way is to play with the binding in order to ignore route parameters. For example you could manually trigger model binding using just form values `TryUpdateModel(model, new FormValueProvider())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint of @DanielJ.G. set me into the right direction.
The problem was the name of the parameter I used for the

```
@Html.ActionLink( ...., new {id = Model.CategoryID}, .....)
```

and the corresponding

```
 public ActionResult Category_Delete(Guid id)
```

As soon as I renamed "id" to "category_id", the ID did not get overwritten anymore.